# Angular 2 complex property binding

Tags: json, angular, angular-directive

I've a model json like this:

```
[{
   "PropName":"disabled",
   "Value":"false"
},
{
   "PropName":"color",
   "Value":"primary"
},
{
   "PropName":"visible",
   "Value":"false"
}]
```

now I need to apply few property to a button, in this case only second element of data model color primary.

```
<button md-raised-button color="primary"></Button>
```

`PropName` value should be replace to **color** property, while Value of data with **primary** value.

Mainly I want to apply one or more property dynamically, form an array of element json with property name and value.
Someone can show me an example ?

thanks

Comment: Make use of [ngStyle] that will do the trick i am sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the logic you will create your object and call it for example elements.

Then in the template:

```
<button *ngFor="let element of elements" [color]="'primary': element.PropName == 'disabled'" [value]="element.Value" md-raised-button color="primary"></Button>
```

Comment: I can't use ngClass, in this case I need to set a property not a css class, the property is color="primary", I am using button of angular material 2

Comment: Check the change I've made in the answer

Comment: Almost... I've an array of elements and not a single element model, i need some thing to search the right element index where property.name ="color"

Comment: Do you mean that you need to set a different color for each element or that you only want to display it if it's a certain color?

Comment: Updated the answer with the needed For loop so it can iterate over the elements.

Comment: You could at least up vote for the time invested in this

Answer (score -1):

I solved so, but I don't know if best pratics:

```
<button md-raised-button  [color]="getColorButton()">
    {{dati.Label}}
</button>
```

from ts component I search color property from model and return value
getColorButton():string {
    if (this.colore!=null) return this.colore;

```
this.dati.Proprieta.forEach(element => {
  if (element.Nome=='color'){
    this.colore =  element.Valore;
  }

});
return this.colore;
```

}